# setBackground cuando el back devuelva un dato diferente

Tags: json, recyclerview

Tengo un problema en un `recyclerView` que hace una llamada a un servidor y me devuelve unos datos.

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que cuando uno de esos datos cambie que me cambiar el `background` de todos los items que contengan ese dato diferente al anterior.

Ejemplo del item:

```
textView: PM5 - COLOR BLUE SHIRT
texView: stock: 1 textView: temporada: 18

textView: PM5 - COLOR BLUE SHIRT
texView: stock: 2 textView: temporada: 18

textView: PM5 - COLOR BLUE SHIRT
texView: stock: 5 textView: temporada: 18
```

Aquí la llamada me devuelve otro producto:

```
textView: PM5 - COLOR RED SHIRT
texView: stock: 2 textView: temporada: 18

textView: PM5 - COLOR RED SHIRT
texView: stock: 5 textView: temporada: 18

textView: PM5 - COLOR RED SHIRT
texView: stock: 3 textView: temporada: 18
```

Me gustaría cambiar el `background` cuando el `textView` que contiene `PM5 - COLOR...` sea diferente al anterior.

Comment: ¿Estamos hablando de `android`? Es que no veo la etiqueta. De todos modos, sin ver el código relevante que estás usando y/o los intentos que has hecho, será difícil poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ya está solucionado, gracias